# Python DEAP - Custom fitness function

Tags: python, genetic, deap, fitness

My question is about the possibility to implement a custom fitness function in DEAP/Python in my Genetic Programming implementation.

After search and reading DEAP official documentation, i don't find anything about it, so, if one of you could help me, i appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need a custom fitness function?

It's a bit confusing, but you might be referring to a custom evaluation function. This should return a number that then the fitness function tries to maximize or minimize.

A great example is https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_onemax.html

In this tutorial, the standard maximizing fitness function is set up:

```
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)
```

followed by the "custom" evaluation function:

```
def evalOneMax(individual):
    return sum(individual),
```

which is then registered to the toolbox:

```
toolbox.register("evaluate", evalOneMax)
```

Comment: Wow! I had not realized this, really that is the right way, thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem. In EC evaluation function is commonly called the fitness function. I think that DEAP uses the evaluation function to map genotype to quality of measure. Then fitness function for comparing this measure.